# Phasing between Boom and radio mics

Tags: offsets, delay

i am editing a fiction where the sound needs often the help of the radio mikes (what i do not like very much)
i have allways between 3 an 12 samples offset between the different mikes.

does there exist a plugin for protools to put the phase of the tracks together or you other guys still do it by hand?
thanks for your answer
george

Answer (score 2):

If I have to do it, I do it by hand. I practically never use both at the same time though. I much prefer to use EQ and multiband compression/expansion (and a touch of reverb if necessary) to match the two as closely as I can, then edit between them...always leaning more towards the shotgun than the lav.

Mixing the two together is often a recipe for a massive headache, and potentially a huge wasted of time.

Comment: I second that. And add this last sentence to be able to send this reply at all.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plug in called Auto Align that I used quite successfully on a show recently, where I had two actors in a green screen studio each with their own mic. Because of the nature of the performance - a beatboxing performance - I needed both mics and the plug in did an admirable job of putting the two mics in phase. However that is a "best case" scenario for the plugin, since it's basically a drum performance. Not sure how well it would work on spoken dialog...

Comment: I'll second Auto Align by Sound Radix.  Helps me out of a spot from time to time when I want to stay with the boom but it may momentarily go off mic or something, so I need to use the signal content of the radio to reinforce.  I find phase matching by hand really frustrating - and nearly always unsuccessful - but when using Auto Align I nearly always hear warmth jump in and phasey elements disappear once Auto Align's made it's offset calculation.  I wouldn't use it for a whole scene though, just for little fixes.   

Comment: hello michael so i tried auto align and i must say it works great.as i only tried a demo i can not see the way it saves the work.
when i have 20 takes with 2 or 3 mikes to align, does it keep the correction or do i have to bounce it. it does not have audiosuite, and to keep the plugin as a insert makes 20ms delay
thanks for your experience
george

Comment: Fiddly I know - but I only had short sections to correct so I just bounced.


Answer (score 0):

you could try your luck with either phase align or vocalign and yes I agree sometimes mixing the two can be tedious and most likely a waste of your time.

Comment: i tried vocaline, but i dident get the same phase ? yes it is a headache
but the radiomikes  sound so much different, i l never get them the same with eq and reverb

Comment: @george - use high and low pass filters to listen to specific bands of the spectrum, and adjust an EQ on the target track just within that band. adjust the positions of the pass-filters and repeat. it will help you focus and give you better results. then just ditch the pass-filters once you've finished moving through the spectrum. for a simpler solution, though i haven't tried it myself, maybe you should test out the demo for DUY Magic Spectrum: http://www.duystore.com/com/magicspectrum.html

Answer (score 0):

There is outboard phase alignment gear available. Unfortunately, I have only used one in my experience (and can't remember who built it) and haven't compared it to any others, but they are pretty handy for situations similar to what you are describing.